# C# Console application, cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'?

Tags: c#, error-handling, console-application

I am super stumped. I am trying to create a program that allows the user to create an "automobile" and declare the make, model, and color of said automobile.

The code is unfinished (and posted below). I get several errors on each of the getters and setters in the Automobile class.

For instance, I get an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string' ." on the line of code that reads `return make` and on the line `make = paramMake` as well as the rest of the getters and setters.

Any ideas?

```
namespace Program_4cs
{
    class Automobile
    {
        //2.
        //a). PDDC
        public Automobile()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
            Console.WriteLine("a). Automobile PDDC set.");
        }

        //PDC
        public Automobile(string paramMake, string paramModel, string paramColor)
        {
            string make = paramMake;
            string model = paramModel;
            string color = paramColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
            Console.WriteLine("a). Automobile PDC set.");
        }

        //b). Getters and Setters
        public string GetMake()
        {
            return make;
        }
        public void SetMake(string paramMake)
        {
            make = paramMake;
        }
        public string GetModel()
        {
            return model;
        }
        public void SetModel(string paramModel)
        {
            model = paramModel;
        }
        public string GetColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
        public void SetColor(string paramColor)
        {
            color = paramColor;
        }

        //c). Speed changing members
        public double GetSpeed()
        {
            return speed;
        }
        public void SetSpeed(double paramSpeed)
        {
            speed = paramSpeed;
        }
        public void IncreaseSpeed(double paramIncreaseSpeedBy)
        {
            speed = speed + paramIncreaseSpeedBy;
        }
        public void DecreaseSpeed(double paramDecreaseSpeedBy)
        {
            speed = speed - paramDecreaseSpeedBy;
        }
        public void ShowSpeed(double paramShowSpeed)
        {
            speed = paramShowSpeed;
        }

        //d). instance members
        private double speed;
        private double make;
        private double model;
        private double color;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //1.
            //Ouput a header in the console
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("1. This is Program-4.");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("How many automobiles would you like to create?");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            int numOfAutomobiles = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Automobile[] listOfAutomobiles = new Automobile[numOfAutomobiles];

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("Please input model, and color");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfAutomobiles.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the make: ");
                String make = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the model: ");
                String model = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the color: ");
                string color = Console.ReadLine();
                Automobile newCar = new Automobile(make, model, color);
                listOfAutomobiles[i] = newCar;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm.. I have an idea! I think that _"Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'"_ means that you cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'.

Comment: Also, if you want to learn C#, you may start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created your instance variable `private double make` you told the program that `make` is of type `double`. In `SetModel(string paramMake)` you take in a string and try to set that as the value of a double. A string is a series of characters, while a double is a floating point value. The compiler can't convert these itself, which is what's giving you the error (similar errors appear elsewhere in the code).

To fix this, we can store the make as a string instead of a double. To do this, we'd change `private double make` to `private string make`. Our other option is parsing the string for a double value. We can do this with `Convert.ToDouble()`.

One questions I think you should consider here is whether a double or a string is the best option for your uses. Storing the model and the color as a double seems like it could be better done by a string, while speed fits well as a double value.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry that was such a stupid mistake...

I've been programming in other languages all day and my brain is pretty fried.

I had the declarations at the beginning of the code initially and I guess I simply skipped over them as I was reviewing my code. I was so focused on figuring out these arrays I completely ignored the other elementaries.

Thanks so much for taking the time on this well thought out response.